# Expressing "someone got someone to do something for me"

Tags: causation, giving-and-receiving

I'm trying to figure out how to say something like:

> Tanaka got Honda to buy me a coffee

The best I could come up with was:

> 田中さんは本田さんに僕のコーヒーを買わせた

Is this correct, or is there a better way to say this?

At first I thought I would have to use もらう but I think that would make it become:

> I got Tanaka to get Honda to buy me a coffee

I went with `僕のコーヒー` here because I thought I couldn't really use に twice, and it would be confusing as to who was being made to buy it.

Comment: I've always wondered myself how to say things which we can easily concatenate in English, like "Abe made Brady make Cindy make Doug buy Emily a coffee".

Answer (score 1):

In this example, the verb 「奢{おご}る」could be used for *buying someone something* or *treating someone to something*. You could then express your sentence in the following way:

> 田中さんが本田さんを（私に）コーヒーを奢らせました。

The verb「奢る」works as follows: 「①が②に③を奢る」where ① is the *treater*, ② is the *treatee* and ③ is the treat. However, in the sentence above, there is no 「本田さんが」because because the subject of that sentence is actually 田中, not 本田.

But if 田中 is the subject, then how can the corresponding verb be「奢る」if he's not the one treating you? The verb form「奢らせる」actually means *to make someone treat* where the「せる」part is actually an auxiliary verb that *does* correspond with 田中 as the subject. You can find out more about it on this [Japanese grammar website](https://www.kokugobunpou.com/%E5%8A%A9%E5%8B%95%E8%A9%9E/%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B-%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%8B).

Note that this expression may sound as if 本田 was forced by 田中, therefore sounding a bit negative. I think that if you are the recipient of a treat, it's best to just stick with「本田さんにコーヒーを奢ってもらいました。」and not mention *why* he bought you coffee.